# Maximal ideal generated by irreducible element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $(c)$ be a non-zero maximal ideal in $R$. Prove that  $c$ is an irreducible element.

Comment: you can prove this by contradiction assuming that there exist an maximal ideal which is generated by an reducible element...

Answer (score 1):

Since $(c)$ is nonzero, you know that $R$ is not a field. Suppose $c=ab$; then $(c)\subseteq(a)$ and $(c)\subseteq(b)$. Since $c$ is not invertible, one among $a$ and $b$ is noninvertible, say it's $a$; then $(a)$ is a proper ideal.

By maximality of $(c)$…